# Uncaught error with jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error in my jquery.timeline.js script.

You can check my page and see the error:
https://vmegastar.com/homepage-business-consulting/

```
Uncaught 
(anonymous) @ jquery.timeline.js?ver=1:1
```

Where is the error?

I´m using jquery 2.2.2 version.

Comment: Post the relevant details directly here with the question, not just as an external link (that I cannot access).

Comment: The problem is that this script checks what host name it currently runs under ... It is currently configured to run under `www.unpezvivo.com` or `www.unpezvivo.com` ... so the question first of all becomes, are you _allowed_ to use this script under the `vmegastar.com` domain …?

Comment: @CBroe you mean this part of the code? : if(_host == Base64.decode('dW5wZXp2aXZvLmNvbQ==') || _host == Base64.decode('d3d3LnVucGV6dml2by5jb20=')

Comment: Yes, that’s the part I am referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, loaded from https://vmegastar.com/wp-content/themes/thegem/js/timeline/jquery.timeline.js?ver=1, has this condition:

```
var _host = document.location.host;
var _protocol = document.location.protocol;
if (_host == Base64.decode('dW5wZXp2aXZvLmNvbQ==') || _host == Base64.decode('d3d3LnVucGV6dml2by5jb20=') || _protocol == "file:") {} else {
throw '';
}
```

I have no idea what the intention there is, but the condition in the `if` returns `false`, hence your uncaught exception. My siggestion is, if you didn't add that condition yourself and this is the plugin you wanted to use:

https://github.com/ka215/jquery.timeline

Then grab this file instead:

https://github.com/ka215/jquery.timeline/blob/master/dist/timeline.min.js